# アプリ内で保存したファイルの一覧を取得したい

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

#### 環境

swift3
Xcode9.0.1

#### 実現したいこと

アプリ内で保存したファイルの一覧を取得したい。

#### 例

下記のディレクトリにアプリ内で"test1.txt" "test2.text"というファイルを作成し保存します

```
documentDirectoryFileURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last
```

その後、上記のディレクトリ内のファイルの一覧を
test1.txt
test2.txt
のように表示したいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

基本的にはyyzさんの回答と同じことなのですが、最近のApple製APIのトレンドではファイル処理の場合でもパス(`String`)ではなく`URL`を渡すというのが主流なので、そちらの書き方をご紹介しておきます。

```
    let documentDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    do {
        let contentUrls = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentDirectoryURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
        let files = contentUrls.map{$0.lastPathComponent}
        print(files) //-> ["test1.txt", "test2.txt"]
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

上記の例だと`files`は、フルパスではなく、ファイル名部分(拡張子は含む)の配列になります。

---

何点か補足。

- ファイル関係の操作が必要になったら、まずは[`FileManager`クラス](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager)に適当なメソッドが無いか探しましょう。
- 1行目で`.last`ではなく`[0]`としているのは、非Optionalな結果を得るためです。
- `lastPathComponent`というのはURL内のパスの最後の要素(ファイルパスの場合、ファイル名部分)を返すプロパティです。Swiftの場合、パス操作用のプロパティやメソッドが`String`型に移入されないので、`URL`で扱える場合はパスよりも`URL`を使った方が便利になることが多いです。

Answer (score 0):

`FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory` で一覧がとれます。

```
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,Foundation.FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)[0]
let items = try! FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: "\(path)")
```

itemsにfile nameの配列が返される。エラー時の処理は、省いています。